# Regex - extract content between double square brackets

Tags: regex, preg-replace, preg-match, regex-lookarounds

I have following string:

```
[[ id1={{TEXT1}} ]] [[ id2={{TEXT2}} ]] [[ id3={{TEXT3}} ]]
```

I want to match content that is closed in double square brackets, using only {{TEXT3}}.
I tried this:

```
\[\[(.*?)({{TEXT3}})(.*?)\]\]
```

But it also matches matches square brackets from the beginning

[image]

Where wanted result is only:

```
id3={{TEXT3}}
```

Comment: Replace the first `.*?` with `(?:(?!\[\[).)*?`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Big thanks! If you want you can add answer, so i'll accept it :D

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Replacing the first .*? with (?:(?![[).)*? solved my problem.
Big thanks to @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 0):

`.*\[\[ (.*{{TEXT3}}) \]\]`

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rHOc.png)

Explanation:
`.*` anything
`\[\[` until [[
`(.*{{TEXT3}})` capture (everything between [[ ]])
`\]\]` match closing ]]

Your regex had .* inside [[ instead of outside, so it was matching the first [[ it finds.